# Complexed SQL group by and having in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query which returns the following results:

```
user_id    contact_id      contact_id2
--------------------------------------
1          45              3
1          null            null
2          433             65
2          433             6789
2          433             5543
3          443             467
3          null            null
4          null            null
5          5564            12
5          null            null
```

I would like to adapt the query to remove any rows where contact_id and contact_id2 are null but only if that user id has a row where it is not null.

So the results would look something like...

```
user_id    contact_id      contact_id2
--------------------------------------
1          45              3
2          433             65
2          433             6789
2          433             5543
3          443             467
4          null            null
5          5564            12
```

See how the user id of 4 still has the null row because it does not have a 'not null' result.

I have tried the following...

```
SELECT user_id, contact_id, contact_id2 FROM user_table
LEFT JOIN contact_table ON .......
LEFT JOIN contact2_table ON ........
GROUP BY user_id, contact_id, contact_id2
HAVING count(contact_id) > 0 OR (count(contact_id) = 0 AND count(user_id) > 1)
```

Not sure what else I can try though.

The original query is huge so I'm hoping you will be able to work with this very simplified version I've put here...

EDIT::

setting the HAVING clause to just count(contact_id)>0 gets all records where contact_id is not null, but now I need to add all other users that are not in this set of results.

Comment: Can a user have more than one row with valid values?

Comment: Yes... see user_id 2

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, do you?

Comment: Yes... user_id is the primary key on user_table, and there are foreign keys to link to the primary keys on the other 2 tables. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well, if you want help with that, then it would be helpful to see proper DDLs for all relevant tables.

Comment: Join on a subquery which filters with HAVING all groups which only have NULLs

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,user_id    INT NOT NULL
,contact_id      INT NULL
,contact_id2 INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (user_id,contact_id,contact_id2) VALUES
(1          ,45              ,3),
(1          ,null            ,null),
(2          ,433             ,65),
(2          ,433             ,6789),
(2          ,433             ,5543),
(3          ,443             ,467),
(3          ,null            ,null),
(4          ,null            ,null),
(5          ,5564            ,12),
(5          ,null            ,null);

SELECT DISTINCT x.user_id
              , y.contact_id
              , y.contact_id2
           FROM my_table x
           LEFT
           JOIN my_table y
             ON y.user_id = x.user_id
            AND y.contact_id IS NOT NULL;
+---------+------------+-------------+
| user_id | contact_id | contact_id2 |
+---------+------------+-------------+
|       1 |         45 |           3 |
|       2 |        433 |          65 |
|       2 |        433 |        6789 |
|       2 |        433 |        5543 |
|       3 |        443 |         467 |
|       4 |       NULL |        NULL |
|       5 |       5564 |          12 |
+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query.

```
select user_id,contact_id,contact_id2 from table where user_id in ( select   distinct user_id from table group by user_id having count(user_id)>1) and contact_id is not null;
```